# Nested search in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, query

Trying to code up a search string in windows Advanced Query Syntax, to find all video files over 1GB *unless* they're MKV format, in which it should only show those above 5GB. (AND it completely excludes two folder trees from the search.) This is the code I have so far, padded out for ease of reading, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
  (
    (
      (
        size:>1gb 
        (type:video AND ext:NOT mkv)
      )
    OR
        (ext:mkv AND size:>5gb)
    )
  AND
    (
      -folder:(q:\working)
    OR
      -folder:(i:\scraps)
    )
  )
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hm... I don't really know AQS, but [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx) suggests that there is no (need for) explicit `AND`. Also, I think the folder exclusions should not be using an `OR`, as you wish to exclude both. When you say "doesn't work", how does it differ from expected behaviour? Is it including results it should not be, showing no results at all, missing some results, etc.? Which specific results are incorrect?

Comment: Missing results, and showing results that shouldn't (such as files on Q:)  -- and the behaviour isn't consistent, but *most* of the time it actually **only** shows files on Q:, the rest of the time showing nothing, regardless of how I arrange my search terms.

Comment: I can get it to work fine with just a "type:video" modifier, and not the MKV filtering, but I'd hoped to refine things further, as that way includes finished and in-progress transcodes, both. It wouldn't be perfect with the MKV terms added, but it *should* weed out most of  the 'finished' results...  if I can get it working!